# Need to access selected data from a excel addin (Visual C#)

Tags: c#, excel-2007, add-in

Im trying to build a addin that can take some a selection of cells from a excel sheet and then put them together in the first cell i have celected. Between the cells there will be a user selected seperator.

example:
I select the 3 cells A1-A3 with the values A B and C
I then bring up my addin and chose the seperator to be ", ".
The addin should then place a the String "A, B, C" in the cell A1.

But I cant figure out how to access the data I have selected in the excel sheet.

Comment: are you using VSTO to interact with excel?

Comment: I think so. Im new to this. I use Visual Studio and create a new project and select the Excel 2010 Add-in  Visual C# template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var range = (Range)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection;
```